# removing duplicates in arraylist java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a logic to check if a list has any duplicates and if it does it removes them and returns a new list with the items that weren't duplicated/removed.Below is the way i tried but didn't work.

```
CustomerResponse response = service.callGetDetails(id,name);
List <Customer> responseList = response.getCustomerList();
CustomerResponse response1 = service.callGetDetails(id,name);
responseList.addAll(response1.getCustomerList());
```

Customer.java:

```
public class Customer{

@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;

@JsonProperty("startDate")
private String startDate;

@JsonProperty("abcAccount")
private AbcAccount abcAccount;

@JsonProperty("accPaList")
private List<AccPaList> accPaList;

@JsonProperty("type")
private String  type;

//Added getter and setter

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    final int prime=31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((abcAccount ==null)? 0 : abcAccount.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((accPaList ==null)? 0 : accPaList.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((id ==null)? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((startDate ==null)? 0 : startDate.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((type ==null)? 0 : type.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(this == obj)
        return true;
    if(obj == null)
        return false;
    if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Customer other = (Customer) obj;
    if(abcAccount ==null){
        if(other.abcAccount !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!abcAccount.equals(other.abcAccount))
        return false;
    if(accPaList ==null){
        if(other.accPaList !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!accPaList.equals(other.accPaList))
        return false;
    if(id ==null){
        if(other.id !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    if(startDate ==null){
        if(other.startDate !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!startDate.equals(other.startDate))
        return false;
    if(type ==null){
        if(other.type !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!type.equals(other.type))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

AbcAccount.java:

```
public class AbcAccount extends GCAcc{
}
```

HeadAcc.java:

```
public class HeadAcc extends GCAcc{
}
```

SouAcc.java:

```
public class SouAcc extends GCAcc{
}
```

AccPaList.java:

```
public class AccPaList{

@JsonProperty("headAcc")
private HeadAcc headAcc;
@JsonProperty("souAcc")
private SouAcc souAcc;
@JsonProperty("accPaDetails")
private ConcId concId;

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    final int prime=31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((headAcc ==null)? 0 : headAcc.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((souAcc ==null)? 0 : souAcc.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((concId ==null)? 0 : concId.hashCode());
    
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(this == obj)
        return true;
    if(obj == null)
        return false;
    if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    AccPaList other = (AccPaList) obj;
    if(headAcc ==null){
        if(other.headAcc !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!headAcc.equals(other.headAcc))
        return false;
    if(souAcc ==null){
        if(other.souAcc !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!souAcc.equals(other.souAcc))
        return false;
    if(concId ==null){
        if(other.concId !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!concId.equals(other.concId))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

ConcId.java:

```
public class ConcId{

@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;
@JsonProperty("version")
private String version;

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    final int prime=31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id ==null)? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((version ==null)? 0 : version.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(this == obj)
        return true;
    if(obj == null)
        return false;
    if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ConcId other = (ConcId) obj;
    if(id ==null){
        if(other.id !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    if(version ==null){
        if(other.version !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!version.equals(other.version))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

GCAcc.java:

```
public class GCAcc{

@JsonProperty("act")
private String act;
@JsonProperty("acctCurrency")
private String acctCurrency;


@Override
public int hashCode(){
    final int prime=31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((act ==null)? 0 : act.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((acctCurrency ==null)? 0 : acctCurrency.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(this == obj)
        return true;
    if(obj == null)
        return false;
    if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    GCAcc other = (GCAcc) obj;
    if(act ==null){
        if(other.act !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!act.equals(other.act))
        return false;
    if(acctCurrency ==null){
        if(other.acctCurrency !=null)
            return false;
    } else if (!acctCurrency.equals(other.acctCurrency))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

Below is the responseList after adding, where duplicate object are in same order:

```
{
"customerList":[
        {
        "id":"123",
        "startDate":"2022-01-29",
        "abcAccount":{
            "acct":"123",
            "acctCurrency":"USD"
            },
            "accPaList":[
            
                {
                    "headAcc":{
                        "act":"67890",
                        "acctCurrency":"USD"
                    },
                    "souAcc":{
                        "act":"5678",
                        "acctCurrency":"USD"
                    },
                    "accPaDetails":{
                        "id":"C012",
                        "version":"12"
                    }   
                },
                {
                    "headAcc":{
                        "act":"000123",
                        "acctCurrency":"AUD"
                    },
                    "souAcc":{
                        "act":"5678",
                        "acctCurrency":"AUD"
                    },
                    "accPaDetails":{
                        "id":"C045",
                        "version":"12"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type":"EDA"
        },
        {
        "id":"123",
        "startDate":"2022-01-29",
        "abcAccount":{
            "acct":"123",
            "acctCurrency":"USD"
            },
            "accPaList":[
                {
                    "headAcc":{
                        "act":"67890",
                        "acctCurrency":"USD"
                    },
                    "souAcc":{
                        "act":"5678",
                        "acctCurrency":"USD"
                    },
                    "accPaDetails":{
                        "id":"C012",
                        "version":"12"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "headAcc":{
                        "act":"000123",
                        "acctCurrency":"AUD"
                    },
                    "souAcc":{
                        "act":"5678",
                        "acctCurrency":"AUD"
                    },
                    "accPaDetails":{
                        "id":"C045",
                        "version":"12"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type":"EDA"
        },
        {
        "id":"456",
        "startDate":"2022-01-29",
        "abcAccount":{
            "acct":"321",
            "acctCurrency":"CAD"
            },
            "accPaList":[
                {
                    "headAcc":{
                        "act":"76899",
                        "acctCurrency":"CAD"
                    },
                    "souAcc":{
                        "act":"8765",
                        "acctCurrency":"CAD"
                    },
                    "accPaDetails":{
                        "id":"C022",
                        "version":"15"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type":"EDA"
        }
    ]
}
```

where in above list two objects having same details,same order (i.e) ["id":123] is duplicate. I have added toString(), equals(), hashcode() in all objects and passing it to hashSet..Duplicates got removed after passing into Set.It works fine.

Where in same response list, i have another object and duplicate, in which data present inside the object are same, added it below, but order is different. duplicates not getting removed in this case.
Below is the responseList after adding, where duplicate object are in different order:

```
{
"customerList":[
        {
        "id":"123",
        "startDate":"2022-01-29",
        "abcAccount":{
            "acct":"123",
            "acctCurrency":"USD"
            },
            "accPaList":[
            {
                    "headAcc":{
                        "act":"000123",
                        "acctCurrency":"AUD"
                    },
                    "souAcc":{
                        "act":"5678",
                        "acctCurrency":"AUD"
                    },
                    "accPaDetails":{
                        "id":"C045",
                        "version":"12"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "headAcc":{
                        "act":"67890",
                        "acctCurrency":"USD"
                    },
                    "souAcc":{
                        "act":"5678",
                        "acctCurrency":"USD"
                    },
                    "accPaDetails":{
                        "id":"C012",
                        "version":"12"
                    }   
                }
            ],
            "type":"EDA"
        },
        {
        "id":"123",
        "startDate":"2022-01-29",
        "abcAccount":{
            "acct":"123",
            "acctCurrency":"USD"
            },
            "accPaList":[
                {
                    "headAcc":{
                        "act":"67890",
                        "acctCurrency":"USD"
                    },
                    "souAcc":{
                        "act":"5678",
                        "acctCurrency":"USD"
                    },
                    "accPaDetails":{
                        "id":"C012",
                        "version":"12"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "headAcc":{
                        "act":"000123",
                        "acctCurrency":"AUD"
                    },
                    "souAcc":{
                        "act":"5678",
                        "acctCurrency":"AUD"
                    },
                    "accPaDetails":{
                        "id":"C045",
                        "version":"12"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type":"EDA"
        },
        {
        "id":"456",
        "startDate":"2022-01-29",
        "abcAccount":{
            "acct":"321",
            "acctCurrency":"CAD"
            },
            "accPaList":[
                {
                    "headAcc":{
                        "act":"76899",
                        "acctCurrency":"CAD"
                    },
                    "souAcc":{
                        "act":"8765",
                        "acctCurrency":"CAD"
                    },
                    "accPaDetails":{
                        "id":"C022",
                        "version":"15"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type":"EDA"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
responseList= new ArrayList<>(new HashSet <Customer>(responseList));
```

Please help.I checked it in forum and tried many cases to have common logic which handle both the cases, nothing works.

Comment: add the code of Customer class to your comment

Comment: Add the `Customer` class to your *question* by clicking on [edit], pasting and formatting as code.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: added the customer class

Comment: A lot of your code could be made shorter, more readable and safer using `Objects.equals()` and `Objects.hashCode()`

Comment: Since it relies on additional classes (`AbcAccount` and `AccPaList`) you should add them as well. And whatever classes `headAcc`, `souAcc` and `accPaDetails` are.

Comment: it returns different hash code, that's typo..sorry

Comment: @user16320675: updated the issue..i have two cases. while passing into set one of the case is working and duplicates got removed.But in another case duplicates not getting removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea about passing it through a Set is correct as adding an object that is equal to one of the contained objects, results in no change. So the culprit is most likely your implementation of `equals()` method. Make sure that this method returns true for the objects that you define as equal and false otherwise. If that will be written correctly then your set will filter out all duplicates. Implementation of `toString()` method is not necessary though.

Comment: @user16320675 yes, of course hashCode() has to be implemented to uphold the consistency contract between hashCode() and equals(). But that is implied. Since OP already wrote that he implemented hashCode() already shows that (s)he already knows this part and I felt that there was no need to mention it again. But yes, it has to be done.

Comment: @user16320675 your point is valid and correct. My answer dealt though not with the fact of what needs to be implemented (since the OP already implemented all that was needed) but trying to predict where the bug that caused malfunction was.